# NHibernate and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, nhibernate, binding

I am having some issues with binding to objects retrieved from NHibernate using lazy loading. I have read some on the issue and am confused on what I need to do to fix things here.

As I understand it the issue has to do with the way NHibernate handles the proxies for things that haven't been loaded yet. Has someone implemented NHibernate using lazy loading and INotifyPropertyChanged?

Right now INotifyPropertyChanged works if I disable lazy-loading, but otherwise no UI elements get updated if they are bound to things which are lazily loaded. I am already a bit in over my head with all of this and the proxy implementation is even more foreign to me so I am not exactly what it is I even need here. :) I am hoping that there is some reasonably simple solution.

Comment: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/07/nhibernate-amp-inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Comment: I tried this, but I am not sure it works for proxies generated by queries with NHibernate. At least it wasn't working for me.

Comment: how (concretely) didn't it work?

Comment: I am having the same issue of no UI updates when lazy loading is off. I put some break points and the intercept function is getting called, as is the create function. In intercept, however, it never gets into the ...== typeof(INotifyPropertyChanged) block, which seems odd to me. It does get into the (invocation...StartsWith("set_")) block though. And it seems if it is getting into that block something should happen on the UI side. As I said, I am struggling with this stuff a bit, but if I can knock this one out then I can get back to making the UI and not have to deal with the data for awhile.

Answer (score 2):

I got this figured out. I needed to follow the example here: 
http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/NHibernate-PropertyChanged-event-and-WPF.aspx

The step that seemed to be missing was that I needed a ProxyFactoryFactory that returned the data binding factory created by this example:
http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/07/nhibernate-amp-inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Hopefully this is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have been proxy your domain using NH Interceptor than everything should work fine. Except if you made mistake on session management, because interception didn't work outside session scope. Did you micro managed your session per method call of your repository?

Actually the best practice for non web base application is managing session per form, maybe you have read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx), that article explain about managing session per form but the solution is a bit dirty, because session distributed in the presenter.

The most cleanest session management I ever seen is [uNhAddins](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins) with Castle Adapter where you only care of [configuration](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/source/browse/trunk/uNhAddIns/uNhAddIns.CastleAdapters/Readme.txt) the rest you program your repository and service naturally. Here is a technical reference : [part 1](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2008/12/conversation-per-business-transaction.html), [part 2](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2008/12/implementing-conversation-per-business.html), [part 3](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/01/using-conversation-per-business.html), [part 4](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/01/aspect-conversation-per.html).

My favorite example is [this one](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/uNHAddins.Examples.SessionManagement), But in context of WPF you should take a look at [this one](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/uNHAddIns.Examples.WPF).

Hope that help.

Comment: some link are broken, because they used mercurial now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the binding is expecting the sender of the property changed event to be the proxy object, but it is in fact the proxy's target object.  This causes the binding to ignore the event.

I had this same issue and I fixed it by implementing a new NHibernate proxy which intercepts subscriptions to the PropertyChanged event and subscribes them to its own event.  Then when the target raises the event it passes it on to the proxy subscribers, but substitutes the sender with the proxy.

I wrote a blog post about it here: http://calebvear.blogspot.com/2011/04/wpf-bindings-not-updating-when.html